# How can I concatenate all the column values in a row, and then concatenate all rows in a DataTable into a single string?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am trying to concatenate all the columns and then all the rows of a DataTable.

I have tried below code:

```
var student = new DataTable();
student.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
student.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = student.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = "Student" + i;
    dr["Country"] = "India";
    student.Rows.Add(dr);
}

List<DataRow> rows = (from DataRow row in student.Rows select row).ToList();

var paramValues = rows.Select(x => string.Format("({0},{1}),", x.ItemArray[0], x.ItemArray[1])).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y).TrimEnd(',');

Console.WriteLine(paramValues);
```

This is giving me output like `(Student0,India),(Student1,India),(Student2,India),(Student3,India)`

This code is fixed for two columns, how can I make it general for any number of columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be something like this

```
var paramValues = String.Join(",", 
                     rows.Select(x => "(" + String.Join(",", x.ItemArray) + ")" ));
```

Comment: I think we should return string[] as second parameter to the string.Join() .It should be something like rows.Select().ToArray(); ??

Comment: @Amitchauhan See *Join(String, IEnumerable<String>)*  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could consider a more traditional approach instead. Sometimes I find Linq less readable and not every scenario are a good fit to use it.
In your case (if even possible) I think that a normal loop conveys better your intentions.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in student.Rows)
{
    // Concatenate all 
    sb.Append("(" + string.Join(",", row.ItemArray) + ")");
    sb.AppendLine();  // Add a new line (or a sb.Append(",") for a comma)
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

**NOTE**
The code above assumes a lot about your table contents. For example, null values could wreak havoc here.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I want format like this : (itemarray1, itemarray2),(itemarray1, itemarray2)

Comment: See the comment in the code that shows the way to have commas between  row values.